# Unable to execute Ghostscript from command prompt

Tags: ghostscript

I have been using this code to reduce the size of a pdf file:

```
cd C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\bin
gswin64c.exe –h
Gswin64c –sDEVICE=pdfwrite –dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 –dPDFSETTINGS=/printer –dNOPAUSE –dQUIET –dBATCH –sOutputFile=D:\path\filename.pdf D:\path\compressed.pdf
```

I am working in Windows 8 command prompt. It was working just last week, but now when I type the  `gswin64c.exe -h` command, I get this error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.25 (2018-09-13)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc. All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: See the file PUBLIC for details.

Error: /undefinedfilename in (\342\200\223h)
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
%interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push

Dictionary stack:
--dict:980/1684(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:78/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your script.

The line :

```
cd C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\bin
```

Should be :

```
cd "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.25\bin"
```